# Como utilizar jQuery dentro de componente - Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, materialize

Entao, estou tendo dificuldades para executar jQuery (inicializar o componente tabs do materialize) dentro de um componente especifico.

Por enquanto o codigo esta assim:

home-logada.component.html

```
<div class="row">

<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
<li class="tab col s4"><a class="green-text text-accent-3 grey darken-4" href="#test-swipe-1">bring2me</a></li>
<li class="tab col s4"><a class="green-text text-accent-3 grey darken-4" href="#test-swipe-2">bring2someone</a></li>
<li class="tab col s4"><a class="green-text text-accent-3 grey darken-4" href="#test-swipe-3">perfil</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="test-swipe-1" class="min-90 col s12 white grey-text text-darken-4"></div>
<div id="test-swipe-2" class="min-90 col s12 white grey-text text-darken-4"></div>
<div id="test-swipe-3" class="min-90 col s12 white grey-text text-darken-4"></div>    

</div>
```

home-logada.component.css

```
.min-90 {
    min-height: 83vh;
}
```

home-logada.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from "jquery";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home-logada',
    templateUrl: './home-logada.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home-logada.component.css']
})

export class HomeLogadaComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('.tabs').tabs();
    }

}
```

Alguem tem alguma ideia para solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Mas o jQuery está funcionando em outros lugares da aplicação?

Comment: Sim, está. Mas tipo, quando eu mudo de local ( / para /home-logada ) eu noto que os componentes do materialize nao estão mais inicializados, ai pra funcionar eu tenho que recarregar a pagina

Comment: E qual é o erro que aparece quando tentas chamar isso?